# Error "Section 'Boto' already exists"

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, boto

I need make new S3 File System (different than existing one). When I'm trying to do it i get

```
Section 'Boto' already exists
```

***I understand, that firstly I need to delete previous Boto connection/ Boto section.***

One question - how can I delete the existing one?

Comment: You'll need to provide a lot more information before anyone can assist you. For example, what do you mean by a "new S3 File System"? (S3 is not a file system.) What are you doing when you receive the 'already exists' error -- show us your code or the command you are using. Feel free to Edit your question to add more details. For tips on asking a good question, see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

Just had to add this code to **init** method:

```
    if 'Boto' in  boto.config.sections():
        boto.config.remove_section('Boto')
```